# Why does the performance of Golang's memmove (copy/append) vary so much?

Tags: performance, go, memory, x86-64, memmove

I recently encountered a performance problem that I can't easily explain. I hope that someone here can help me understand why these two pieces of code perform *so* differently.

(Code snippets in this text are simplified. The actual code can be seen in [this file on Github](https://github.com/zolstein/segio-parquet-go/blob/c5282b6f187683237efb492e57d6fcec68b165dd/buffer_pool.go).)

I'm attempting to refactor code in a library, without causing a performance regression. In order to do that I need to implement an in-memory `io.Writer` that I can continuously append to without doing expensive realloc-and-copy operations as `bytes.Buffer` does. My solution is to use a slice-of-byte-slices and allocate new byte-slices as I write - the outer slice will need to be realloced, but it's relatively small compared to the size of the data, and the actual data never needs to be copied once written.

```
type noReallocWriter struct {
    data [][]byte
    idx  int
    off  int
}
```

In my first implementation, all the individual byte-slices were allocated with a fixed capacity and on `Write` I would copy into them until full, then allocate a new one. I assumed it would benefit from always having large buffers of contiguous data and needing to allocate somewhat infrequently. (And in fact it does in other places, but not when writing.)

```
func (w *noReallocWriter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    lenP := len(p)
    if lenP == 0 {
        return 0, nil
    }
    for len(p) > 0 {
        if w.idx == len(w.data) {
            w.data = append(w.data, make([]byte, 0, FIXED_SIZE))
        }
        curData := w.data[w.idx]
        n := copy(curData[w.off:cap(curData)], p)
        w.data[w.idx] = curData[:w.off+n]
        w.off += n
        p = p[n:]
        if w.off >= cap(curData) {
            w.idx++
            w.off = 0
        }
    }
    return lenP, nil
}
```

However, this implementation performed worse than the earlier version of the code I was trying to refactor. To help diagnose the issue, I wrote another version to more-closely mimic the behavior of the old, faster code. The new version allocates a new (variable-capacity) byte-slice for every write and copied the data into it.

```
func (w *noReallocWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if w.idx != len(w.data) {
        panic("noReallocWriter only supports appending to the end.")
    }

    if len(p) == 0 {
        return 0, nil
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 0, len(p))
    buf = append(buf, p...)
    a.data = append(a.data, buf)
    a.idx++
    return len(p), nil
}
```

In a very stripped-down synthetic test just writing a bunch of data to these writers, they perform about the same. However, when used (also in a synthetic test, but) in the context of my application, the second version performed much better. In both cases, (basically) all of the time is spent in `memmove` (copy / append) moving data from the passed in byte-slice (b) to the byte-slice stored inside the Writer. However, the version with fixed-size byte-slices spends 3-4x the time in `memmove`, and the time is split between the lines 372-375 of [memmove_amd64.s](https://go.dev/src/runtime/memmove_amd64.s). By comparison, the version with variable-sized buffers spends all of it's time on line 375. Normally I might not trust a profiler's analysis of assembly by line-number, but that measurement is *very* consistent.

```
365:    // Aligned memory copying there
366: gobble_128_loop:
367:    VMOVDQU (SI), Y0
368:    VMOVDQU 0x20(SI), Y1
369:    VMOVDQU 0x40(SI), Y2
370:    VMOVDQU 0x60(SI), Y3
371:    ADDQ    AX, SI
372:    VMOVDQA Y0, (DI)
373:    VMOVDQA Y1, 0x20(DI)
374:    VMOVDQA Y2, 0x40(DI)
375:    VMOVDQA Y3, 0x60(DI)
376:    ADDQ    AX, DI
377:    SUBQ    AX, BX
378:    JA  gobble_128_loop
```

I don't really understand the assembly, but I'm not sure how one implementation can spend so much time in lines 372-374 and the other doesn't, when they copy the same amount of data, mostly in similarly-sized chunks, and nothing jumps directly to line 375.

I ran performance profiles, which you can see [here (fixed-size)](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7101542/270265110-19ccc198-c122-4db7-8bc1-2493b5f9c1e6.svg) and [here (variable)](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/7101542/270265150-721137e4-11a1-488e-a14c-48f6fd56365c.svg).

Some notes about the testing that generated those profiles:

In both versions, the application writes the same data in the same pattern. In practice, write sizes alternate between small (35 bytes) and large (just under 256KB, but variable). I tested the first version with different FIXED_SIZE values between 32KB and 1MB - performance was about the same from 64KB to 256KB and lower above or below that.

Comment: Sorry, my Go is rusty: what is the purpose of this line `w.data[w.idx] = curData[:w.off+n]`?

Comment: Sorry I just briefly skimmed your question, but cache hit vs. miss, and/or page-fault on freshly allocated memory can in general be one reason for the same vector store instructions to take much longer in one run than in others.  If the loads miss in cache, the stores (which depend on the load results) will get the blame in profiling tools that use HW performance counters.  ([Inconsistent \`perf annotate\` memory load/store time reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65906312), and in general [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987))

Comment: @MargaretBloom That line updates the length of the slice stored in the object to reflect the data that was copied in.

Comment: "If the loads miss in cache, the stores (which depend on the load results) will get the blame in profiling tools that use HW performance counters."

@PeterCordes Fascinating if true. I definitely need to re-test with perf or similar and see if there's a major difference in the cache miss rate.

Comment: [Unexpectedly slow performance on moving from register to frequently accessed variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76773814) is a simpler example of just that effect, also on an Intel CPUs.  (With some speculation on my part about the causes.)  Another common effect is that an instruction one or two later than the stall get the blame when the event counter overflows and an interrupt is raised to take the sample.)